# New to programming having problems

Tags: java, syntax

I know that the \n should provide me with a new line when utilized. With \n before text being it will put a new line before the text and with it after will create a new line after the text. However, I have written my code, see below, and the new line isn't created unless I also put the \n in the method of my created class as well. Would someone please help me understand why?

Without the \n in my system.out.println line of my method, this doesn't happen. It will come out like this:

```
Houston Store:
Gross Revenue is $...
Seattle Store:
Gross Revenue is $
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Houston Store:
Gross Revenue is $...

Seattle Store:
Gross Revenue is $....
```

code:

```
        System.out.println("Houston Store:");
        houstonStore.grossRevenue();

        System.out.println("\nSeattle Store: ");
        seattleStore.grossRevenue();

        System.out.println("\nOrlando Store: ");
        orlandoStore.grossRevenue();
    }

}
class groceryStore {

    int applesSoldYearly;
    double priceOfApples;
    int orangesSoldYearly;
    double priceOfOranges; 

    //methods to calculate gross revenue & then print to the screen when called

    void grossRevenue() {
        double revenue;

        revenue = (applesSoldYearly * priceOfApples) 
                + (orangesSoldYearly * priceOfOranges);

        System.out.print ("Gross Revenue is $" + revenue);

    }
```

Comment: Hi, your question seems little unclear. Can you please elaborate on your question as in what do you expect from your program and how is it different from what you are getting as output?

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: Hello. To clarify your question use [edit] option placed under it. Sometimes there will be suggested edits so you will need to make decision about them first.

Comment: I'm working in Windows utilizing Eclipse IDE. However, from what I understand if I put "\nOrlando Store: ") it should put a space before it prints that to the screen. However, it doesn't do this unless I also add the \n to the system.out.println statement in my method as well. I confused as to why there is no line separator before it outputs the store names

Comment: If you're confused about \n, just remember its the same thing as pressing the enter key.

Comment: JoeChris, That is what I understand it to do. However, it won't happen unless I put it both in my print statement of my main method and also the print statement of my grossRevenue method. Shouldn't it work if I just put it in my main method like my code show?

Comment: Notice that in expected `Gross Revenue is $...` `Seattle Store:` you have two line breaks, like `Gross Revenue is $...\n\nSeattle Store:` one to move cursor to new line after `$...` and second to move cursor from that empty line to yet another line. But TBH most often we don't manually place `\n` or `\r` in our code, instead we use `println(data)` (with `ln` suffix) which generates output like `data+(OS dependent line separator)`. Also your `grossRevenue` method shouldn't internally print its value but simply return it. Then in main method you could take it and decide how you want to print it

Comment: But aside from your question, you may not know it yet but question title isn't to state *that* you have problem, but to put *short description* of problem you are facing, so others with same problem would be able to find it easier.

Comment: Thank you everybody

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is coming from your mixed use of System.out.println and System.out.print (without the 'ln').  Since you are using System.out.print in grossRevenue, it isn't adding the newline at the end.  Changing that statement to use System.out.println should give you the intended output.